# Memory management while implementing a generic linked list library in C

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

I'm implementing a generic Linked List in C

```
struct Node
{
  void* data;
  struct Node* next;
};
```

Is it better to let the user worry about allocating and deallocating what data will point to, or should we do it ourselves? If left to the user they may store stack objects into the list which could cause problems later. I just wanted to know which design is better.

Comment: not to use `void *` in the first place.

Comment: A user may want to store stack objects, why not. Or static ones.

Comment: @KirilKirov - Would you go through customs with a package that you do not know the contents of or what it could possibly do?

Comment: @EdHeal - OK, how you would implement _generic_ linked list?

Comment: @EdHeal it's not the purpose of a generic link list to know what data will be stored in it, it should just link all nodes together so you can enumerate it...

Comment: @DipSwitch - In C you have no option - In C++ (where this person could score some extra points) could use a template in C++

Comment: @EdHeal But since this post is tagged as C and not C++ a `void*` would suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general **rule of thumb** is *usually*: **Who allocates a memory - is responsible for freeing it**.

In your case, you should take care for the nodes themselves, and the user should be responsible for the `data`.

It makes sense because:

1. By taking responsibility on the nodes- it gives you more freedom to change implementation in future versions, without needing to worry about backward compability.
2. You cannot know *how* and *if* to free `data` - it could be a complex type that needs freeing in inner fields as well, or it could be pointing to a stack allocated space, which will cause an error if trying to free it.
3. In addition, remember that if a user took an element out of the
   list - it does not mean he wants to destroy the data. Maybe the
   list is a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29), and the element is currently being processed by
   him?

Comment: This is what I was looking for ... any other potential dangers in trying alloc - dealloc user supplied data ourselves ?

Comment: @user1616513: The main problem is it could point to a memory you cannot free without expecting errors/undefined behaviors (some examples I can get is: pointer to an automatic allocated variable, pointer to a string literal,...)

Comment: @Samhan Also: I added another reason: If an element is out of the list - it does not mean the data is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a function that takes a function pointer and data type to deallocate in your generic link list. User can supply customized code in the function and pass pointer to that function to execute their version of code to free the allocated memory in the complex data type, e.g. nested structures that need to be traversed or a structure that has multiple pointer variables that need to be deallocated as well.
Following is a snippet for this idea.
main.c

```
int int_data;  /* int can be replaced by any other data type */
deallocate_data(user_defined_free, &int_data);

void user_defined_free(void *data)
{
    int *i = (int *)data;    
    /* cast to your data type and 
     perform deallocation */
}
```

somewhere in your generic linked list code

```
void deallocate_data (void (*p)(void *), void *data)
{
  /* call user defined function to free their data structure */
    p(data);
}
```